# How to decompose efficiently dpoibin into its summands in R?

Tags: r, probability, probability-theory, probability-distribution, bernoulli-probability

The Poisson-Binomial distribution concerns the probability of the number of successes in a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with different probabilities of success. This is a generalization of the Binomial distribution.

With the command `dpoibin`, in the `poibin` package, one can obtain the mass probability function. For instance, with this command:

```
library(poibin)
n <- 100
Probs_Success <- runif(n)
dpoibin(kk = 30, pp = Probs_Success)
```

one can obtain the probability of getting 30 successes in a sequence of 100 independent Bernoulli trials with probabilities of success contained in the vector `Probs_Success`. To compute this probability one has to sum the probabilities of all possible sequences of lenght 100 where there are 30 successes and 70 failures.

**Question:** How can I efficiently obtain all of the summands that generate the above probability in R? Thanks a lot for your help.

For those who are interested in the problem that motivated this question, please click on the following link:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924831/bivariate-poisson-binomial-distribution

Comment: Not sure what question is about. Isn't  `dpoibin` already doing it for you? Or you want code which independently verify `dpoibin` output?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, @SeverinPappadeux. The R-command dpoibin provides the sum of all summands. I need the set of all summands to perform another operation with them. I am writing the reason that motivates my question. I will let you know when I finish.

Comment: There are 100 choose 30, which is 29372339821610944823963760 terms in a naive expression for that.  There is no efficient way to generate that list.  I would strongly reconsider how you're trying to perform the other operation so that you don't need to work with the whole list.  (I presume that `dpoibin` uses a dynamic programming technique to keep from working with the whole list itself.  Anything else would be a disaster.)

Comment: I appreciate your interest, @btilly. Thanks for the advice. I am working on a problem that motivates my question. I will let you know when I finish to write this problem.

Comment: Dear @btilly, I updated my question with a link to the problem I am working on if you are interested on it. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @SeverinPappadeux, I updated my question with a link to the problem I am working on if you are interested on it. Thanks.

Comment: I answered this question there.  I answered it in Python rather than R because I know that language better.  Hopefully the translation isn't too hard for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @btilly. In addition, I will take advantage of it to learn Python.

Comment: Did you look at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947312003568?via%3Dihub

Comment: Yes I did, @SeverinPappadeux. In addition, I am examining the direct convolution algorithm Biscarri et al. (2018) propose.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947318300082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem that motivated the above question. This solution is based on the paper

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610918708812585

To see this solution, just click on the following link

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924831/bivariate-poisson-binomial-distribution

Thank all people who provided me suggestions.